What is the correct way to std::move a parameter into a class constructor?
The basic version of my situation looks like this.
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<int> v)
        : m_vector(v) {}

    void doSomething();

private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    // ...
    // Do stuff with myVector
    // ...
    
    MyClass myItem(myVector);
    myItem.doSomething();
}

Obviously it is more efficient to move the vector into MyClass rather than copy it, but I am never sure how to define the constructor of MyClass and how to pass the argument when instantiating it.
The following versions all compile correctly.
A:
MyClass(const std::vector<int>& v)
    : m_vector(std::move(v)) {}

MyClass myItem(myVector);

B:
MyClass(std::vector<int> v)
    : m_vector(std::move(v)) {}

MyClass myItem(myVector);

C:
MyClass(const std::vector<int>& v)
    : m_vector(v) {}

MyClass myItem(std::move(myVector));

D:
MyClass(const std::vector<int>& v)
    : m_vector(std::move(v)) {}

MyClass myItem(std::move(myVector));

E:
MyClass(std::vector<int>&& v)
    : m_vector(std::move(v)) {}

MyClass myItem(std::move(myVector));

...and I'm just getting more confused. I guess the question is not even which one is "correct", but which one guarantees the least copies?

I think there is a canonical dupe for this that asks exactly this.Should I always use std::move in a constructor?

Moving-construct a const-lvalue just does a copy, so A/C/D are wrong in that regard.

Prefer E if you want to disallow implicit copy.

Also Passing a parameter to a function with std::move, is there a difference if that parameter is declared as pass-by-value or with a move operand &&? and Taking sink parameters by rvalue reference instead of by value to enforce performant usage of interfaces

My project uses this rule:  if it is a sink parameter, then pass-by-value.  (But that's not without contention.  Some team members would rather have sink parameters always be pass-by-&&.)  Then std::move the parameter into the object's member variable for retention in the initialization list.
